# Convert dictionary values into array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, dictionary

What is the most efficient way of turning the list of values of a dictionary into an array?

For example, if I have a `Dictionary` where `Key` is `String` and `Value` is `Foo`, I want to get `Foo[]`

I am using VS 2005, C# 2.0

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
// dict is Dictionary<string, Foo>

Foo[] foos = new Foo[dict.Count];
dict.Values.CopyTo(foos, 0);

// or in C# 3.0:
var foos = dict.Values.ToArray();
```

Comment: Does the extension .ToArray<Foo>() perform any better?

Comment: but how do we know that it's the most efficient ?

Comment: I can't see how ToArray() could be any faster than the straight copy - which seems to be minimalistic.

Comment: @Tom I usually take the view that anything built into the framework (like .CopyTo() or .ToArray()) is the most efficient way to do it. The Microsofties are smarter than me. :)

Comment: ToArray is less performant than CopyTo (it uses CopyTo to copy to an internal intermediate representation, and then Copy again to return it out). However, as with all micro-performance related matters go for readability, robustness and maintainability and measure performance if it's an issue.

Comment: ToArray() is an extension method in LINQ, so you need to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 17):

Store it in a list. It is easier;

```
List<Foo> arr = new List<Foo>(dict.Values);
```

Of course if you specifically want it in an array;

```
Foo[] arr = (new List<Foo>(dict.Values)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a ToArray() function on Values:

```
Foo[] arr = new Foo[dict.Count];    
dict.Values.CopyTo(arr, 0);
```

But I don't think its efficient (I haven't really tried, but I guess it copies all these values to the array). Do you really need an Array? If not, I would try to pass IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = dict.Values;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to use linq, so you can try following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var arr = dict.Select(z => z.Value).ToArray();
```

I don't know which one is faster or better. Both work for me.

Comment: `dict.Values.ToArray()` does the same thing, but without the overhead of materializing each value through a delegate.

Answer (score 3):

These days, once you have LINQ available, you can convert the dictionary keys and their values to a single string.

You can use the following code:

```
// convert the dictionary to an array of strings
string[] strArray = dict.Select(x => ("Key: " + x.Key + ", Value: " + x.Value)).ToArray();

// convert a string array to a single string
string result = String.Join(", ", strArray);
```